# Rescaling preserves sign of eigenvalues or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

**I want to show a matrix$\begin{bmatrix}
  L & L_S\\ \alpha L_S&\alpha L
 \end{bmatrix}$ whose eigenvalues all have non-negative real parts.**

where $\alpha$ is an arbrtrary positive scalar. $L$ and $L_S$ are Laplacian-type matrices of an undirected graph $\mathbb{G}$ defined as follows.
Let $W\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be the adjacency matrix of graph $\mathbb{G}$ such that $W[i,j]=w_{ij}$, with $w_{ij}=1$ if $(i,j)\in\mathcal{E}$ and $w_{ij}=0$ otherwise. Let a diagonal matrix $D\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$ be the degree matrix of graph $\mathbb{G}$, where $D[i,i]=d_i=\sum_{j\in\mathcal{N}_i}w_{ij}$. Then
\begin{align}
 L[i,j]&=\begin{cases}   
   ~~-w_{ij}& \text{for}\quad i\neq j\\
   \displaystyle\sum_{j\in\mathcal{N}_i,j\neq i}w_{ij}& \text{for}\quad i=j 
  \end{cases}\\
 L_S[i,j]&=\begin{cases}
  %~~~0& \text{for}\quad  j\notin\mathcal{N}_i\\
  ~~-s_{ij}=-w_{ij}& \text{for}\quad i< j\\
        ~~-s_{ij}=w_{ij}& \text{for}\quad i> j\\
  \displaystyle\sum_{j\in\mathcal{N}_i,j\neq i}s_{ij}& \text{for}\quad i=j 
 \end{cases}
 \end{align}

Example: $L=D-W=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&-1\\-1&1&0\\-1&0&1\end{bmatrix}$;
$L_S=\begin{bmatrix}2&-1&-1\\1&-1&0\\1&0&-1\end{bmatrix}$

Remark: I can prove that
$\begin{bmatrix}
  L &L_S\\ L_S&L
 \end{bmatrix}$
has eigenvalues with non negative real parts because it is similar to the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
 L-L_S &\\ &L+L_S
\end{bmatrix}$. By Gershgorin Circle Theorem and the definitions of $L$, $L_S$, both $L+L_S$ and $L-L_S$ have eigenvalues with non-negative
real parts (Re$(\lambda)\ge 0$).

However, I'm not able to prove the proposed statement.
Here, $L_S$ is not symmetric, which is the main challenge. If you don't consider its diagonal components, it has a skew-symmetric structure.

Comment: *"By Gershgorin Circle Theorem and the definitions of , , each block has non-negative eigenvalues."* What does "non-negative" mean here? The traditional meaning is $\lambda_k \geq 0$ but unless all Gerschgorin Discs are disjoint you generally can't make that inference so maybe you mean $Re(\lambda_k)\geq 0$ or maybe mean that the $\lambda_k$ live in the complex slit plane (with the negative half line deleted).  In any case what you mean needs clarified.

Comment: You are right, I made modifications to the statements.

Comment: It looks like $L-L_S$ and $L+L_S$ are each triangular, so the eigenvalues will be exactly the diagonals, and you write down the formulas for them as something like $\lambda_i = 2\sum_{j < i} w_{ij}$ and $\lambda_j = 2\sum_{j < i} w{ij}$ for $i,j= 0, 1, 2, \dots, m$. Looks like the matrix will be singular, which precludes any argument about the sign of the determinant...